# Replacing rails model object key with ruby hash value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails model object as shown below

```
[#<Object id: 876,  input_type: 4, require_level: true>,#<Object id: 877,  input_type: 4,  require_level: true>, #<Object id: 878, input_type: 2, require_level: true>]
```

Input_types is a hash as shown below

```
input_types = {"w"=>1, "x"=>2, "y"=>3, "z"=>4}
```

I would like to get output as follows based on the input_type attribute replacement

```
[#<Object id: 876,  input_type: 4, require_level: true>,#<Object id: 877,  input_type: 4,  require_level: true>, #<Object id: 878, input_type: 2, require_level: true>]
```

I have the following code:

```
objects.each do |object|
   replacement_key =  input_types.key(object.input_type)
   object.attributes["input_type"] = replacement_key
end
```

This does not produce any result and return the object as it is in the initial stage

Comment: If you have an answer, then post it as an answer and **not** as edit to your question please. Question for question and answers for answers ;) You can accept it after 2 days as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
new_objects = objects.map do |object|
  replacement_key =  input_types.key(object.input_type)
  object.input_type = replacement_key
  object
end.as_json
```

Comment: This returns an array ["z", "z", "x"] but I wan the entire object

Comment: Put `object` as the very last line in the block to return the whole object.

Comment: Sorry @Jefferson, I updated my answer. Thank you mudasobwa

Comment: This  works after converting the model object to json. Tried the above edit too but not getting any result

Comment: We have no JSON info in this answer man. I don't know what you're talking about

Comment: Why are you converting to json before? Couldn't you do that at the end, on `new_objects` array?

Comment: I updated my code to add the `as_json` as well. Try again with that exactly code and let me know what is the problem

Comment: [#<Object id: 876,  input_type: 0, require_level: true>,#<Object id: 877,  input_type: 0,  require_level: true>, #<Object id: 878, input_type: 0, require_level: true>] This throws wrong o/p

Comment: Are you sure you're using map and not each?

Answer (score 0):

This works out. Any better ways without json?

```
objects = objects.as_json
objects.each do |object|
  replacement_key =  input_types.key(object["input_type"])
  object["input_type"] = replacement_key
end
```